# view, edit and save edits for large number of plots in r

Tags: r, graph, plot

I have a list of 1000 of dataframe (each with 4 columns with same name). I want to draw plots and work on them interactively. The following is example (with 3 dataframe for single list).

```
# dummy data 
c1 <- rnorm (40, 0.1, 0.02); c2 <- rnorm (40, 0.3, 0.01)
c3 <- rnorm (40, 0.5, 0.01); c4 <- rnorm (40, 0.7, 0.01)
c5 <- rnorm (40, 0.9, 0.03)
Yv <- 0.3 + rnorm (200, 0.05, 0.05)

 # frist dataframe 
    var1 <- data.frame (idnames = paste ("ID", 1:200, sep = ""), Theta = round (c(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5), 2), R = round (Yv, 2),     cltr = c(rep(1:5, each = 40)))

# same dummy data filled in second dataframe 
var3 <- data.frame (idnames = paste ("ID", 1:200, sep = ""), Theta = round (c(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5), 2), R = round (Yv, 2),     cltr = c(rep(1:5, each = 40)))

    # same dummy data filled in third dataframe
    var_5 <- data.frame (idnames = paste ("ID", 1:200, sep = ""), Theta = round (c(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5), 2), R = round (Yv, 2),     cltr = c(rep(1:5, each = 40)))

 # the list (the original list has >1000 dataframes)
    mylist <- list (var1 = var1, var3 = var3, var_5 = var_5)
```

I want to create plots of each dataframe with are similar, but I need to work one by one and  save the out and move to next plot

```
# plot for var1
myd1 <- data.frame (mylist[1])
names (myd1) <- c("idnames", "Theta", "R", "cltr")
plot(myd1$Theta, myd1$R, col=myd1$cltr+1, pch = 19, main = names (mylist[1]))
exclude <- identify(myd1$Theta, myd1$R)
## left click on the points you want to exclude (right click to stop/finish)
myd1$cltr1 <- as.numeric ( myd1$cltr)+ 1
myd1$cltr1[exclude] <-  1
plot(myd1$Theta, myd1$R, col=myd1$cltr1, pch = 19, main = names (mylist[1]))
```

[image]

I can do same for other dataframes in the list, for example for 2:

```
myd2 <- data.frame (mylist[2])
names (myd2) <- c("idnames", "Theta", "R", "cltr")
plot(myd2$Theta, myd1$R, col=myd2$cltr+1, pch = 19, main = names (mylist[2]))
exclude <- identify(myd2$Theta, myd2$R)
## left click on the points you want to exclude (right click to stop/finish)
myd2$cltr1 <- as.numeric ( myd2$cltr)+ 1
myd2$cltr1[exclude] <-  1
plot(myd2$Theta, myd1$R, col=myd2$cltr1, pch = 19, main = names (mylist[2]))
```

I have some problems:

(1) I want to loop the process and one plot pops us at one time and when editing is done the plot is closed and new plot for next dataframe pops up to work and so on and continued to last dataframe in the list.

(2) In stead of creating new dataframe, is it possible to loop process within the parent list and save changes to it.

Help appreciated.

Comment: is there no way to automate this task? 1000 manual edits seem like a [heavy enough load](http://xkcd.com/1205/) to see first if it can be done more efficiently.

Comment: I do not find one, not perfect as human can do, but I think it is worth do so even if it is hours or days work, now I am concern about loops, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to get into the details of exactly what you want to do on each plot, but I would construct a function that does whatever plotting and saving you want to do, include a `scan` line to wait for user input that then triggers the next iteration of the loop.

```
plotwait <- function(){ # could pass arguments for saving, etc.
    x <- rnorm(100,0,1)
    y <- rnorm(100,0,1)
    plot(y~x)
    # other stuff you want to do to plot here
    z <- scan(nlines=1,quiet=TRUE) # wait for any input
}

for(i in 1:1000)
    plotwait()
```